# Django no spaces between letters in textfield

Tags: django

So I am trying to create a guitar website and here, spaces are very important between letters as different chords are played at different times, so when I entered all my information from the admin panel in the `textfield` of my `Songs model` I entered all the spaces correctly, but when the song is being rendered all those spaces are gone, and all the chords are written one after another. What can I do to fix this?

My admin panel:

[image]

My website:

[image]

My models.py:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    lyrics = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='favorite_songs'
    )
    track_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('/', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Try `<pre>{{ song.lyrics }}</pre>`. (It is normal behaviour in HTML for spaces to be rendered as only one space)

Comment: This is due to the HTML rendering which considers one or more spaces to be equal to *one* space.